# Accept bitcoin on behalf of charity

Tags: charity

I would like to start accepting bitcoin donations on behalf of a set of charities that don't accept it.  I'm thinking this may be a stepping stone to get them to accept bitcoin directly because they will see money coming in.  I don't want to take any fee or commission... just convert into fiat and pass 100% to the charities.  Does anyone have experience doing this?  Do I need permission from the charities?

Comment: You might find that ethical problems arise. How can we trust you?

Comment: What ethical problems?  As far as trust, I can be totally open and post all my receipts online for when I pay fiat to the charity, and you can match that to the blockchain, which would show how much BTC I've received on their behalf and when.  Of course everyone is free to not trust me and either donate directly to the charity in fiat or not donate at all.  I'm just providing an option.